# mysql updates not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, updates

I have a mysql insert function that works whenever I insert data into a database, but my mysql update function for some reason doesn't seem to work... it doesn't return any data... just zilch... not even an error message... here's the code: hopefully you can figure out why it's not responding by upgrading the database - primary column/key here is "id" or "$id" - which auto increment itself - I changed the id to pop out random values as well - still get same results... here's the code - hopefully you can fix it up!

```
    if ((isset($_POST["submitd"]) && $_POST["submitd"] == "Save" ) && (strlen((string)$id)==0)&& (strlen($first_name)>0) && (strlen($middle_names)>0) && (strlen($last_name)>0) && (strlen($street)>0) ){

    $full_name = $first_name." ".$middle_names." ".$last_name;

 $query567="INSERT into records(id,full_name, first_name, middle_names, last_name, street) VALUES('$id','$full_name','$first_name', '$middle_names', '$last_name', '$street');";
 $vttvk = $dbs -> prepare($query567);
 $vttvk -> execute(array(':id'=>$id,':full_name'=>$full_name,':first_name'=>$first_name,':middle_names'=>$middle_names,':last_name'=>$last_name,':street'=>$street));

    }
else {  
    $query257 = "UPDATE records SET `full_name`=?,`first_name`=?, `middle_names`=?,`last_name`=?,`street`=? WHERE `id`=?";

    $opztyz51 = $dbs->prepare($query257);

    $opztyz51 ->execute(array($full_name, $first_name,$middle_names, $last_name, $street, $id));
}
```

I hope you can help fix this up....

Comment: have you tried echoing your insert string and just using it in SQL? Does it work? Lots of time it is typos

Comment: Your `insert` statement does not seems a prepared statement. You put the variable directly inside the query.

Comment: For one, you're using prepared statements completely wrong.

Comment: `$full_name = $first_name." ".$middle_names." ".$last_name;`, and then putting all four in the table, is breaking 3NF by the way. Sometimes that's desirable for speed but, if so, it should really be done by a trigger so that the data remains consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that the error is caused by your prepared statement. If you have this:

```
$query567="INSERT into records(id,full_name, first_name, middle_names, last_name, street) VALUES('$id','$full_name','$first_name', '$middle_names', '$last_name', '$street');";
```

Then `:id`, `:full_name`, etc. are nowhere to be found in the query, and the variables specified by the array can't be binded to anything. I think you meant to do something like:

```
$query567="INSERT into records(id,full_name, first_name, middle_names, last_name, street) VALUES(:id,:full_name,:first_name,:middle_names,:last_name,:street);";
```

That way you're also using prepared statements correctly.

Comment: i edited it bud...it's still not working...u have any clue as to how else i can fix this up?

Comment: @JosejosemartinezMartinez check the error: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php